# Consultar JSONField desde un mixins.ListModelMixin con Django Filter Backends

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, djangorestframework, django-urls

Quisiera consultar un campo JSONField desde la URL de un endpoint en django rest framework y que este me retornase la coincidencia que exista dentro de un campo JSONField del modelo.

El siguiente es el modelo:

```
class TestJsonGuard(models.Model):
   idtest = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   product = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   json_leader = JSONField()
```

La siguiente es la vista desde donde deseo realizar la consulta:

```
class TestGuardJson(mixins.ListModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):

   permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
   queryset = TestJsonGuard.objects.all()
   serializer_class = TestJsonGuardSerializer
   parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
   filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
   filterset_fields = ["product", "json_leader"]
   search_fields = ["product", "json_leader"]
   pagination_class = Pagination

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Estoy intentando enviar algo de esta manera desde la URL:

```
/api/v1/test?json_leader__active_substance__contains=VITAMINA C
```

Pero ello no me funciona para lograr encontrar las coincidencias en el JSONField almancenado en la base de datos, cuya estructura es:

```
[{"active_substance": "VITAMINA D"}, {"active_substance": "VITAMINA A"}, 
 {"active_substance": "VITAMINA B"}]
```

El error que me lanza al intentar consultarlo de esa manera es:

```
AutoFilterSet resolved field 'json_leader' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type 
JSONField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'.
```

¿cómo podría configurar la vista adecuadamente sin afectar los demás campos que el modelo posee y que se pueda consultar en ellos?

Comment: Es posible que el espacio en la url `VITAMINA C` esté dando problemas suele ser útil hacer `urlencode()` antes de enviar la solicitud para evitar líos con caracteres que puedan ser interpretados como separadores.

Comment: pero la configuración del endpoint como tal si es la correcta? , porque la prueba la estoy realizando desde Postman y creo que el internamente ya hace el urlencode